# I want to import type from another assembly into current module using mono.cecil

Tags: c#, cil, mono.cecil

Assembly.write method throws the following error

Member 'XXX.LoggingAspectAttribute' is declared in another module and needs to be imported

Ive included the following lines in my code

```
 var type = _module.Import(typeof(LoggingAspectAttribute));
 _module.Import(type.Resolve().Methods.First(m => m.Name == "OnExecute"));
 _module.Import(type.Resolve().Methods.First(m => m.Name == "OnException"));
 _module.Import(type.Resolve().Methods.First(m => m.Name == "OnComplete"));
 _module.Import(typeof(LoggingAspectAttribute)).Resolve();
```

where module is defined as the main module of the assembly

```
_module = ModuleDefinition.ReadModule(filename, new ReaderParameters()
        {
            ReadSymbols = true
        });
```

Any ideas on how to fix this error?

Comment: Here's a user with a similar issue using Mono.cecil: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34879710/member-is-declared-in-another-module-and-needs-to-be-imported.

Comment: Its not clear from that question whats the fix to my issue.

Comment: @VasudhaGupta try to remove tha last row `_module.Import(typeof(LoggingAspectAttribute)).Resolve();`

Comment: @dudiKeleti Even after removing the same error is there.

Comment: @VasudhaGupta Do you have any usage of the imported method? Can you show us the fuul code?

Comment: Here is the code that i am using .. https://github.com/scmccart/Reweave.. When i try to put LoggerAspectAttribute in another assembly - Reweave.Core it gives error in the Assembly.write method.

Comment: Maybe have a look at this [git repo](https://github.com/markusschweitzer/ILRewriter) it is pretty similar.

Answer (score 0):

ModuleDefinition.Import() does not import anything into the module, it simply returns a reference to the metadata from the module's point of view.

Try this:

```
TypeReference type = _module.Import(typeof(LoggingAspectAttribute));
MethodReference onExecute = _module.Import(typeof(LoggingAspectAttribute).GetMethod("OnExecute"));
MethodReference onException = _module.Import(typeof(LoggingAspectAttribute).GetMethod("OnException"));
MethodReference onComplete = _module.Import(typeof(LoggingAspectAttribute).GetMethod("OnComplete"));
```