# Fody: Copy an attribute from one property to another

Tags: c#, aop, fody

I iterate through all classes, then all properties, then their attributes. When I see an attribute MetaAttribute(typeof(SomethingElse)) I find a property named Target on that class and copy all of its properties across to the current property on the class in the module being worked on by the weaver...

For example

```cs
public class Person
{
  [Meta(typeof(PersonTitleMeta))] // <- Identifies the source
  public string Title { get; set; } // <- The target property
}

public class PersonTitleMeta
{
  [Required, MinimumLength(2), MaximumLength(16)] // These get applied to Person.Title
  public object Target { get; set; }
}
```

This works fine when the `PersonTitleMeta` is in the same assembly as `Person`

```cs
foreach (var currentSourceAttribute in sourceAttributes)
    property.CustomAttributes.Add(currentSourceAttribute);
```

But when they are in different assemblies it does not work
`System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.RequiredAttribute::.ctor()' is declared in another module and needs to be imported`

Could someone please tell me how to copy the attribute across from a different assembly?

Comment: Maybe this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34879710/member-is-declared-in-another-module-and-needs-to-be-imported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be doing the trick, but is it the correct way to do it?

```cs
        private CustomAttribute CloneAttribute(CustomAttribute sourceAttribute)
        {
            MethodReference sourceAttributeConstructor = sourceAttribute.Constructor;
            MethodReference localAttributeConstructorReference = ModuleDefinition.ImportReference(sourceAttributeConstructor);

            var localCustomAttribute = new CustomAttribute(localAttributeConstructorReference);
            foreach (var sourceAttributeConstructorArgument in sourceAttribute.ConstructorArguments)
            {
                TypeReference localAttributeTypeReference = sourceAttributeConstructorArgument.Type;
                CustomAttributeArgument localAttributeInstance = new CustomAttributeArgument(localAttributeTypeReference, sourceAttributeConstructorArgument.Value);
                localCustomAttribute.ConstructorArguments.Add(localAttributeInstance);
            }

            return localCustomAttribute;
        }
```